# Best way to import a csv file of users and managers, then email the manager with a list of their users

Tags: powershell, csv

forgive me for breaking any rules. I'm a brand new StackOverflow user, and a powershell noob. I'm working on a work project where I import a CSV file that contains a list of users and their respective managers. I then need to create an email that contains a table with the users for each respective manager.

I know how to import the csv file. I've gotten a basic email sending code created. I'm completely lost as to how to appropriately get the users and managers associated with each other.

For example, my csv is formatted with headers like this:

```
First Name  Last Name  Username   Manager 
Bob         Dole       BDole      Jsmith 
John        Doe        JDoe       Anoob 
Jane        Doe        JDoe1      Jsmith 
etc.
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I've tried using a hashtable and an array, with no success. This is likely due to my noob status.

Please let me know if there is more information I should add. I don't have any real code written at this point since nothing has worked, so please pardon the very limited code in the post.

```
$users = import-csv "Path goes here"

"My code for associating the users and managers would go here"

 "Email code goes here"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users = Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

$cred = Get-Credential # enter the credentials for your email account
```

from where you will send the mail

```
$users | Group-Object -Property Manager | % {
    $managername = $_.name
    write-host $managername
    $body = $_.group | format-table | ConvertTo-Html
    write-host $body
    Send-MailMessage -to "$managername@some.com" -Body $body -From "yourmail" -SmtpServer "yoursmtpserver" -Port "your smtp port" -Subject "mailsubject" -Credential $cred -BodyAsHtml
}
```

If you dont want to enter your mail credentials every time you can save them as following.

```
get-credential | export-clixml -path "somepath"
```

later on you can read the credentials from you os:

```
$cred = import-clixml -path "somepath"
```

Comment: This will only send 1 mail per manager. if you comment out send-mailmessage. You can run it to test it. The group object wil make groups based on the manager property. try running only ($users | Group-Object -Property Manager)

Comment: I realized that after the fact! My mistake.

Comment: My last question is, when the emails are generated, the results don't look as nice as they do in the console.

They come out misaligned. Like the spaces aren't in there anymore.

Comment: `format-table | ConvertTo-Html` and `Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml` I also added it to my answer

Comment: This is the out

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title> </head><body> <table> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></
colgroup> <tr><th>ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd</th><th>pageHeaderEntry</th><th>pageFooterEntry</th><th>autosizeInfo</th><th>shapeInfo</th><th>groupingEntry</th></tr> <tr><td>033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Micro
soft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo</td>

Comment: yes its html it should look fine in an email (mind that you have to use send-mailmessage with the -BodyAsHtml switch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure I understand what kind of output you want, but here is a suggestion. If you have a csv file named workers.csv, this should sort entries by the manager name:
contents of workers.csv:

```
first   last    username    manager
john,   doe,     jdoe,        boss1
jan,    doe,     jjdoe,       boss2
jim,    ddi,     jddi,        boss2
didi,   goo,     didigoo,     boss1
```

at the Powershell prompt, type:

$managers = "boss1","boss2"

(then type enter ) 
then type:

```
foreach ($item in $managers) {         
   cat ./workers.csv | Select-String -Pattern "$item"
   | out-file -append workers.csv
}
```